# How can I get the source of a compiled handlebars template?

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

I'd like to modify a compiled Handlebars template, like:

```
var template = Handlebars.templates.my_path.to.original_template
var source = template.magic // ??
var modifiedTemplate = Handlebars.compile($(source).append('Also: {{something}}'))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is apparently no way to get the source back without modifying `Handlebars`.

Moreover, as we are using `rails-handlebars`, it would be even more involved. :-(